# information hiding , polymorphism and scalability

Tags: java

I've got a few questions:

**1)** given a class named **class WavPanel extends JPanel**

Can I say that :

a) it's an example of inheritance

b) it's an example of polymorphism since the class WavPanel methods override JPanel methods?

**2)** is a private method within a class, an example of information hiding?

**3)** adding a method to a class ( a new functionality) , can I say that the application is scalable?

Those questions may sound trivial to you but they are vital to me.

Thanks a lot.MAX

Comment: Sounds like you don't want to do your homework... :)

Comment: It's not homework..it's that I need to understand...thanks

Answer (score 4):

a) true: keyword "extends"

b) true, if WavPanel would override some JPanel-methods. false, if it just would add functionality (e.g. new methods).

c) false
Since a method is not a piece of "information" - it's an interface or an ability of the class - private methods do not hide information. (see comment, too)

d) false:
Scalability usually is not reached by inheritance or new methods. An application using object composition is much more scalable and dynamic than one based on inheritance. Additionally, adding new methods changes the interface of a class. So all users of the class must be updated in order to benefit of this change, what means that you have write code => scalability is very low.

Comment: Why a private method is not an example of information hiding? The private method adds functionality to the application but in order to avoid interferences I set it private

Comment: I just updated the answer. But it's just about how you define "information". Information = Data in my answer. So you're right, in some way private methods hide Information of "how" a class does something. Public methods should just expresses the "what".

Comment: Thanks..With reference to scalability, what I wanted to say is that since my application consists of a couple of classes and two threads,if I wanted to add a new feature I would resort to adding a new method (a private one) to the first class. By doing this can I say that my application is scalable?

Comment: It's very hard to speak generally. But just adding new methods does not make your application scalable. Otherwise, every application would be scalable, which is definitely not true. You should study object composition and design patterns.